# TypeError: (_jestResolve || _load_jestResolve(...)).default.findNodeModule is not a function

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have a project set up with Webpack 4 and Babel 6 and want to upgrade to Babel 7. I installed the following packages:

```
+    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
+    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
+    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
+    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
+    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
+    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
+    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
+    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
```

... and removed the old ones:

```
-    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
-    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
-    "babel-plugin-react": "^1.0.0",
-    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
-    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
-    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
-    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
-    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
-    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
-    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
-    "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
```

But now whenever I run Jest, I get this error...

```
TypeError: (_jestResolve || _load_jestResolve(...)).default.findNodeModule is not a function
    at exports.resolve (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest-config/build/utils.js:67:64)
    at Object.keys.map.regex (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest-config/build/normalize.js:649:51)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.keys.reduce (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest-config/build/normalize.js:647:34)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at normalize (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest-config/build/normalize.js:545:24)
    at readConfig (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest-config/build/index.js:184:68)
    at getConfigs (/Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:473:77)
    at /Users/jgallaso/Projects/3scale/porta/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:251:23
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well turned out all I needed was to install `"babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0"` as well.

In the end what I used was [babel-upgrade](https://github.com/babel/babel-upgrade), it installed all missing packages indluding the bridge.